# missing "Edit Enterprise Library V5 Configuration"

Tags: wcf, enterprise-library

I installed Entlib 5 .

In existing WCF application, I see "edit wcf configuration"

But I don't see  "Edit Enterprise Library V5 Configuration"  -Any idea why it is missing?

Answer (score 5):

Check Tools | Extension Manager whether the EntLib config tool is actually installed.

If not, you can install it from the Visual Studio Extension Gallery:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/029292f0-6e66-424f-8381-3454c8222f9a
or search for 'entlib' from the Extension Manager.

Also, make sure the config file you are trying to do a right click on, actually has the <configuration> element. The config tool VSIX checks for that before lighting up.